# d3: axes being scaled/zoomed, not multi-line graph. How can I fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am plotting dates on the x-axis against cumulative integers on y-axis. I have been trying to implement a feature to be able to scale/zoom into the graph as well as move it. However, I am failing to do this - the axes are changing but the graph is not.

This is my code:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom");//.tickSize(-height);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left");//.ticks(5);

// Define the line
var cumulativeline = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("linear")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.cumulative); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 250)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + margin.left  + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip")
.append("rect")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

// Get the data
d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.cumulative = +d.cumulative;
});

var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.a_tradeidtype;})
    .entries(data);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.cumulative; })]);

// Loop through each a_tradeidtype / key
dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) { 
svg.append("path")
        .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
            return d.color = color(d.key); })
        .attr("class", classname)
        .attr("d", cumulativeline(d.values))
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
});

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

// Create zooming component
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on('zoom', zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);
});

function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating your lines in 'zoomed', just the axes. You need something like this in the function:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return cumulativeline(d.values); })
;
```

I also suspect you may need to change the original append routine to something like the below to have data joined to each path so the above code can work:

```
// Loop through each a_tradeidtype / key
svg.selectAll("path").data(dataNest)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .style("stroke", function(d) { // Add the colours dynamically
            return d.color = color(d.key); })
        .attr("class", classname)
        .attr("d", function(d) { return cumulativeline(d.values); })
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
;
```

If this doesn't work, stick your code in a jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I added
`svg.selectAll("path").attr('d', function(d) { return cumulativeline(d); });`

and:
`svg.append("path").datum(data)
            .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
   .attr("class", classname)
            .attr("d", cumulativeline(d.values))
   .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");`

This fixed it. Thank you!